# Fail to run cmake with cygwin

Tags: c++, c, cygwin, cmake

I am having a problem with cmake under cygwin. I installed the cygwin's CMake package AND the normal CMake package (in windows) and every time I run CMake to configure a project it displays the following:

```
$ CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:/home/LordEvil/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeCCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:/home/LordEvil/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/LordEvil/build/tool." does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

What is this problem? Can anyone help to resolve this problem?

Comment: Found the problem.

I needed to install the make, gcc and gcc-c++ packages that come with setup.exe from cygwin.

Comment: You should post that as an answer (you might have to wait a while).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Found the problem. I needed to install the make, gcc and gcc-g++ packages that come with setup.exe from cygwin.

Comment: You mean `gcc-g++`? `gcc-c++` doesn't exists.

Comment: maybe? It's been 5 years since I last used cygwin, I might have made a mistake at the time.

Answer (score 6):

Another reason you might see this message is if Make isn't installed